# test equality of 2 string on python error

Tags: python, string, testing, equals

```
from optparse import OptionParser
usage = "usage: %prog [options]"
parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)
import sys
print("Please choose the type of agent")
line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

i have put random and when i test what line looks like it give me random

```
parser.add_option("-p","--player1",dest="player1",
                  default=str(line),help="Choose type of first player")
```

i want to  test if the value in entry are equal but it returns nothing why the default parameter can't learn the value str(line) i try also for line withour str

```
if str(opts.player1)=='random':
    print ('true')
```

Comment: Unless you need backwards compatibility, you should use `argparse` instead of `optparse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `sys.stdin.readline()` retains the newline, so the value of `line` is `'random\n'`, not `'random'`. You need to strip it first:

```
parser.add_option(..., default=str(line.strip()), ...)
```